# Scala, Json & Spring Boot Rest

Tags: json, scala, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a Rest API using spring boot and Scala based on the below suggestion. I am successfully able to call the methods in Scala but the case class is not working the way it is designed.

When I try to create a Json using `net.liftweb.json`, I am getting additional string as `"$outer":{}`. I don't want this additional string in my output.

Note that the spring boot is expecting class instead of object. I suspect this could be an issue. Can you help me on this.

My case class looks like this:

```
case class BasicSrch(size: String, query: Match)
```

**Erroneous output**

```
{"$outer":{},"size":"10","query":{"$outer":{},"match":{"$outer":{},"_all":{"$outer":{},"query":"SNOW","operator":"and"}}}}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"size":"10","query":{"match":{"_all":{"query":"VALLE","operator":"and"}}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing UTF-8 encoded JSON to the byte array or OutputStream then try jsoniter-scala: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala

It will not serialize any other fields except those which are defined in a primary constructor of the case class.

Comment: I don't see more information to get a answer for my problem. Could you help to point which one could resolve my issue. I already developed that code which is working as expected in the stand alone jar. The problem created after integration of the Rest API with spring boot.